# Haskell: Understanding algebraic data types better

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I'm trying to construct an algebraic data type that represents polynomials.  Given the definition that an Integer constant is a polynomial and that if you add two polynomials or multiply two polynomials, it results in a polynomial.

I'm having a difficult time understanding how algebraic data types work in general and how I would even go about producing this.  I currently have

```
data Poly = Const Int | 
            Add Poly Poly | 
            Mult Poly Poly
```

However I don't know what this even means or how to use it, I'm simply going off of examples I've seen of algebraic data types.

I've seen types like

```
data Tree = NullT |
            Node Int Tree Tree
```

That makes more sense to me, and how to use it.  The polynomial example seems so abstract I don't know where to start.

Edit: When I try to implement simple testing functions like:

```
evalPoly :: Poly -> Int
evalPoly (Const n) = n
```

I'm met with the error

```
*Polynomial> evalPoly Poly 1

<interactive>:25:10: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Poly’
*Polynomial>
```

Edit again: Thank you for all your suggestions and help, it's helped me produce something that's working for my purposes!

Comment: You have ask yourself what kind of operations you want to perform on your polynomials and then try to implement them.

Comment: @augustss I have a few that I will need to implement later, but for now I want to focus on understanding the definition of it and how to use the definition.

Comment: With this `Poly` type, you might have an expression like `Add (Mult (Const 2) (Const 3)) (Add (Const 1) (Add (Const 3) (Const 4)))`, which would be equivalent to `(2 + 3) * (1 + (3 + 4))` if you were to evaluate it in the canonical manner.

Comment: @bheklilr So if I wanted it to be able to represent like `2x^3` I'd have to have something like
`data Poly = Const Int |
             Variable Int Char Int`
?

Comment: You'd be better off with something like `data Poly = Const Int | Var Char | Add Poly Poly | Mult Poly Poly | Pow Poly Poly`.  Just add a new constructor for each operation you want.

Comment: you're confusing the type (`Poly`) with its constructors (`Const`, `Add`, `Int`); `Const 1` constructs a `Poly`; `Poly 1` can't

Comment: @daf Ah thank you!

@bheklilr Thank you, that helps me somewhat.  Wouldn't Pow just be `Pow Int`?

Comment: No. `3^2` would be `Pow (Const 3) (Const 2)`

Comment: You would construct it like `Pow (Var 'x') (Const 3)` for `x^3`.  It would also let you do things like `Pow (Var 'x') (Add (Var 'y') (Const 2))` for `x^(y + 2)` for more complex equations.

Comment: @bheklilr Ah thanks that makes sense.  I think for the purposes of this little program, I won't be needing to put poly's to the power of polys, just display polys.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: This is a horrible example to for an ADT, just because a set is closed under an operation doesn't mean that the operations should be used as constructors

Comment: FWIW, you'd probably be better off representing polynomials (in a single variable) as a list of tuples: `x^2 + 2x^7 = [(1, 2), (2, 7)] :: [(Coefficient, Exponent)]`, say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want to make an ADT for polynomials, but I'd prefer to use a Map. First some imports:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Function (on)
```

A polynomial is a Map from powers of x to coefficients.

```
newtype Poly a n = Poly {coeffMap :: M.Map n a} deriving (Show)
lift f = Poly . f . coeffMap
```

Let's make some simple polynomials:

```
zero = Poly M.empty                  -- none of the powers have non-zero coefficients
x = Poly $ M.singleton 1 1           -- x^1 has coefficient 1

constant 0 = zero
constant a = Poly $ M.singleton 0 a  -- x^0 has coefficient a
```

A standard thing to do with a polynomial is evaluate it with a particular value for x.

The fold here takes the partially-calculated `b` and adds on the new term, `a*x^n`:

```
evalAt :: (Num a, Integral n) => a -> Poly a n -> a
evalAt x = M.foldrWithKey (\n a b -> b + a*x^n) 0 . coeffMap
```

If we want to use a Map function, we can lift it from `Map n a` to `Poly n a`.
I'd like to be able to map on the coefficients, but I don't want to make this an instance of Functor because it's a classic student error to apply operations like squaring, applying trigonometrical or logarithmic functions or taking square roots term by term, when in fact only a tiny few things like scalar multiplication, differentiation and integration work like this. Providing fmap encourages you to do wong things like `fmap (+1)` instead of `(+ (constant 1))`.

```
mapCoeffs :: (a -> b) -> Poly a n -> Poly b n
mapCoeffs f = lift (fmap f)
```

Maps already collect like terms automatically, but we'll want to omit terms with zero coefficients:

```
strikeZeros :: (Num a,Eq a) => Poly a n -> Poly a n
strikeZeros =  lift $  M.filter (/= 0)
```

Now we can make the instances:

```
instance (Eq a,Num a,Ord n,Num n) => Eq (Poly a n) where
   f == g = f - g == zero

instance (Eq a,Num a,Num n,Ord n) => Num (Poly a n) where
   fromInteger = constant . fromInteger
   signum (Poly m) | M.null m = zero
                   | otherwise = let (n,a) = M.findMax m in 
                        Poly $ M.singleton n (signum a)
   abs =  mapCoeffs abs
   negate = mapCoeffs negate
   (+) = (strikeZeros.) . (Poly.) . ((M.unionWith (+)) `on` coeffMap)
   (Poly m) * (Poly m') = Poly $ 
          M.fromListWith (+) [(n+n',a*a') | (n,a)<-M.assocs m, (n',a')<-M.assocs m']
```

In action:

```
ghci> 3*x^4 + 6 + 2*x^7
Poly {coeffMap = fromList [(0,6),(4,3),(7,2)]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative solution to the other one I posted.

You seem to want to make an ADT for polynomials, where I'd use a Map, but let's go with a list of terms. First some imports:

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (sortBy, groupBy, foldl1')
```

This way a polynomial is a list of terms, sorted with the highest power first, and a term is aX^n, represented by `X a n`

```
newtype Poly a n = Poly {terms :: [Term a n]} deriving (Show)
data Term a n = X {coeff :: a, power :: n}  deriving (Eq,Show)
```

Let's make some simple polynomials:

```
zero = Poly []
x = Poly [X 1 1]

constant :: (Num a,Eq a,Num n) => a -> Poly a n
constant 0 = zero
constant a = Poly [X a 0]
```

Once we've defined the Num instance, we'll be able to make `X 3 4` by writing `3*x^4`.

A standard thing to do with a polynomial is evaluate it with a particular value for x.

```
subst :: (Num a, Integral n) => a -> Term a n -> a
subst x (X a n) = a * x ^ n

evalAt :: (Num a, Integral n) => a -> Poly a n -> a
evalAt x = sum . map (subst x) . terms
```

I'd like to be able to map on the coefficients, but I don't want to make this an instance of Functor because it's a classic student error to apply operations like squaring, applying trigonometrical or logarithmic functions or taking square roots term by term, when in fact only a tiny few things like scalar multiplication, differentiation and integration work like this. Providing fmap encourages you to do wong things like `fmap (+1)` instead of `(+ (constant 1))`.

```
mapCoeffs :: (a -> b) -> Poly a n -> Poly b n
mapCoeffs f = Poly . map f' . terms
  where f' (X a n) = X (f a) n
```

We'll need to add and multiply terms, and collect like terms. When we collect like terms, we sort in reverse order of power and omit terms with zero coefficients.

```
addTerm (X a n) (X b m) | n == m = X (a+b) n
                        | otherwise = error "addTerm: mismatched powers" 
multTerm (X a n) (X b m) = X (a*b) (n+m)

collectLikeTerms :: (Num a, Ord n, Eq a) => Poly a n -> Poly a n
collectLikeTerms =  Poly . filter ((/= 0).coeff)            -- no zero coeffs
                         . map (foldl1' addTerm)            -- add the like powers
                         . groupBy ((==) `on` power)        -- group the like powers
                         . sortBy (flip compare `on` power) -- sort in reverse powers
                         . terms
```

Now we can make the instances:

```
instance (Eq a,Num a,Ord n,Num n) => Eq (Poly a n) where
   f == g = f - g == zero

instance (Eq a,Num a,Num n,Ord n) => Num (Poly a n) where
   fromInteger = constant . fromInteger
   signum (Poly []) = zero
   signum (Poly (t:_)) = constant . signum . coeff $ t
   abs =  mapCoeffs abs
   negate = mapCoeffs negate
   (+) = (collectLikeTerms.) . (Poly.) . ((++) `on` terms)
   (Poly ts) * (Poly ts') = collectLikeTerms $ Poly [multTerm t t' | t<-ts, t'<-ts']
```

In action:

```
ghci> 5*x^2 + 6*x^7 + 2
Poly {terms = [X {coeff = 6, power = 7},X {coeff = 5, power = 2},X {coeff = 2, power = 0}]}
```